# Connect to a database instance with many instance on the net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I tried to connect to a SQL Server database on the internet via an Asp.net application that is on my local system.

The database is on a server with IP x.x.x.x and on the server we have 3 instances of SQL Server 2005: `instance1/MSSQL2005` and `instance2/MSSQL2005` and `instance3/MSSQL2005`.

I can't connect with my application to the `instance1/sqlserver2005` on the database XXX on this instance !

This its my connection string that didn't work :

```
<add name="VestaWSEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server = x.x.x.x ;Data Source=Instance1\MSSQL2005;Initial Catalog=MyDB ;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance names don't look correct.

Usually a SQL instance is specified in the format `server\instance`

given the information in the question, it should be something like

```
x.x.x.x\instance1
x.x.x.x\instance2
x.x.x.x\instance3
```

Can you connect to the instances in SSMS? You should use the same value in the data source in your connection string

Try replacing this in your connection string

```
server = x.x.x.x ;Data Source=Instance1\MSSQL2005;
```

to this

```
Data Source=x.x.x.x\instance1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;
```